# Each loop only showing last instance

Tags: jquery, each

Hi I am having issues with my each loop. When I run the outer each loop, the data logged shows the last instance multiple times instead of showing each instance.

It seems like the issue is with the .push because the log of the_data works properly

```
//Set variables
var links = [];
var the_data = [];

//Loop through each instance of .section
$.each($('.section'), function(index, item) {

    //find all instances of .item within .section
    var data = $(this).find('.Item');

    //loop through each instance of .item and find all data attributes and add them to an array
    $(data).each(function() {
        var name = $(this).attr('data-name'); 
        the_data[name] = $(this).val();
    });

    //log the_data to check
    console.log(the_data);

    //push the_data array into links
    links.push(the_data);
});

//log links to check
console.log(links);
```

Here is the console output:

```
[articleTitle: "title", articleOutlet: "outlet", articleLink: "link", articleExcerpt: "Excerpt"]
[articleTitle: "title 2", articleOutlet: "outlet 2", articleLink: "link 2", articleExcerpt: "Excerpt 2"]
[Array[0], Array[0]]0: 
Array[0]articleExcerpt: "Excerpt 2"articleLink: "link 2"articleOutlet: "outlet 2"articleTitle: "title 2"length: 0__proto__: Array[0]1: 
Array[0]articleExcerpt: "Excerpt 2"articleLink: "link 2"articleOutlet: "outlet 2"articleTitle: "title 2"length: 0__proto__: Array[0]length: 2__proto__: Array[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you do `links.push(the_data)` you're pushing the same array onto the `links` array. It doesn't make a copy of it. You should initialize `the_data` inside the outer `$.each()` loop. Also, it looks like `the_data` should be an object, not an array, since you're storing `name: value` pairs into it. Arrays are for numerically-indexed data.

```
//Loop through each instance of .section
$.each($('.section'), function(index, item) {
    var the_data = {};
    ...
}
```

Comment: Arrays can be indexed by key too, although an object *is* probably a better choice here.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie True, but if you log an array it won't show the named properties.

Comment: Agreed. It was wasting the array-ness of the object.

Answer (score 1):

`the_data` is a single array, initialised once in your example. Your code is pushing that same array onto the `links` *each time*, so of course it shows the same data more than once.

You need to reset the `the_data` to a new array inside the outer `each` loop

```
$.each($('.section'), function(index, item) {
    the_data = [];
```

or just declare it inside the outer loop:

```
$.each($('.section'), function(index, item) {
    var the_data = [];
```

As you appear to be using `the_date` as a name/value dictionary, and not as an array, you might as well declare it as an object:

```
$.each($('.section'), function(index, item) {
    var the_data = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are overwriting the first entry with the second entry.